# Button that opens new Panel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to create a `JFrame` for my game that will be the main menu. Now, I asked myself how should I go in to a new panel in the same frame??

Yes, I haven't started on the menu because I maybe have to redo everything if I've done something wrong.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GameWindow {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle("Rampage Rush");
        window.setSize(1000, 800);
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 800)); 
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Android tag removed -- your question has absolutely nothing to do with Android programming. You'll want to be more careful with your question tagging since using correct tags are the best way to get appropriate experts to view your problem, and inappropriate tags will do the opposite.

Comment: Next, you'll want to edit your question and write a coherent and understandable question. Maybe it's me, but I haven't a clue as to what it is you're asking.

Comment: You state something about using a button to create a new panel (JPanel?), but I don't see any JButton code or ActionListener code in the code you've posted suggesting that you have not yet read the JButton tutorial. If not, then you should do this first. Check out [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) to get to the Swing tutorials.

Answer (score 3):

> how should I go in to a new panel in the same frame??

Based on your vague statement I would guess you should be using a `CardLayout`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and examples.